# How to make all v-card equal height with vuetify2

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Getting crazy with this, i want to size all v-cards in an vuetify2 project equal. My the center (v-card-text) has different count of chars (text). Tested with a fixed height of v-card-text, but no scrollbar as expected if text is longer.

This a the markup for one v-card component:

```
 <template>
  <v-card class="elevation-5" fill-height>
    <v-card-title primary-title>
      <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{ name }}</h3>
    </v-card-title>

    <v-card-text>
      <div class="body-1">{{ description }}</div>
      <v-divider light style="margin-top:15px;" />
      <v-divider light />
    </v-card-text>

    <v-card-actions v-if="showButtons">
      <v-btn color="green">
        <a :href="url">VISIT</a>
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

This is the parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-row class="ma-2">
      <v-col md="4" class="pa-3" v-for="i in items" :key="i.id">
        <Item :show-buttons="true" :item="i" />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

The Parent is placed in:

```
     <v-content>
      <v-container fluid ma-0 pa-0>
        <router-view />
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
```

Please see this screen, may be this makes my bad english better to understand.

[image]

Comment: would be nice if you can put this on codesandbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the height and the overflow in the text area:

```
<v-card-text style="overflow-y: auto; height:100px" >
  <div class="body-1">{{ description }}</div>
  <v-divider light style="margin-top:15px;" />
  <v-divider light />
</v-card-text>
```

It is better to do it by a `class`, but I use `style` here for an easy grasp.

Answer (score 21):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'A', description: 'Short', showButtons: true },
        { id: 2, name: 'B', description: 'Short', showButtons: false },
        { id: 3, name: 'C', description: 'Longer text that wraps onto multiple lines', showButtons: true }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@3.9.97/css/materialdesignicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.17/dist/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.17/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>

<div>
    <v-row class="ma-2">
      <v-col md="4" class="pa-3 d-flex flex-column" v-for="i in items" :key="i.id">
        <v-card class="elevation-5 flex d-flex flex-column">
          <v-card-title primary-title>
            <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{ i.name }}</h3>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text class="flex">
            <div class="body-1">{{ i.description }}</div>
            <v-divider light style="margin-top:15px;"></v-divider>
            <v-divider light></v-divider>
          </v-card-text>

          <v-card-actions v-if="i.showButtons">
            <v-btn color="green">
              <a>VISIT</a>
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I've added the classes `d-flex`, `flex-column`, and `flex` in a few places but otherwise it should be equivalent to the code posted in the question. The `d-flex flex-column` makes the parent a flex-box column and then `flex` sets the child to `flex: auto`, so that it stretches to fill the space. There's a subtlety here in that the available space is defined by the tallest item, so there's a circularity of sorts.

Comment: This works thank you. How can you make all the heights equal though for every line?  Say you have 9 cards. 3 cards each row

Comment: It works, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You just have to set 'align' property to "stretch" in v-row:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-row align="stretch" class="ma-2">
      <v-col md="4" class="pa-3" v-for="i in items" :key="i.id">
        <Item :show-buttons="true" :item="i" />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 7):

`class="fill-height"` on the cards works for me:

```html
<v-row>
  <v-col v-for="i in 8" :key="i" lg="4">
     <v-card class="fill-height">...</v-card>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```