# Auto-align content of cards in rows with vuetify?

Tags: html-table, alignment, vuetify.js, card

I want to have a table / cards mixture in Vuetify. The "rows" of the cards must be aligned, since they contain data to be compared. The height of each row should be variable, adapting to the card with the longest text in this row. Something similar is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34124044/4420271) using JavaScript.

Can someone answer showing a basic Vuetify example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make all v-card equal height with vuetify2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941447/how-to-make-all-v-card-equal-height-with-vuetify2)

Comment: This should work if it's only one row in the card that has variable height.

Comment: @Yitz You mean the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57946991/4420271), right? There are potentially more than 1 rows that need variable height. So it would help a bit, but it is not covering all I need. Thank you nonetheless!